# Trace form of Frobenius Norm of Matrix approximation

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, trace

I'm a CS Student and I've implemented the Convex Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (Convex-NMF) Algorithm for a project.

Now, for "classic" NMF algorithms, you get an approximation:

$$
\mathbf{A} \approx \mathbf{WH}
$$

with the goal is to minimize

$$
\| \mathbf{A-WH} \|_F^2
$$

which, according to [1] can be written as
$$
\| \mathbf{A-WH} \|_F^2 = trace(\mathbf{A^TA}) - 2*trace(\mathbf{H^TW^TA}) + trace(\mathbf{H^TW^TWH})
$$

I've tried to understand it, and apply it to Convex-NMF, where the approximation is written as $\mathbf{X} \approx \mathbf{XWG^T}$

So I thought that:
$$
\| \mathbf{x-XWG^T} \|_F^2 = trace(\mathbf{X^TX}) - 2*trace(\mathbf{X^TXWG^T}) + trace(\mathbf{X^TXWW^TGG^T})
$$

where
$$
\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, \quad \mathbf{W,G} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}
$$
(and some more constraints, that don't matter here).
Well, the result I get is wrong, so I guess I messed up the math somewhere (which isn't my strong suit).

[1] Amy N. Langville, Michael W. Berry, Murray Browne, V. Paul Pauca, and Robert J. Plemmons. *Al-
gorithms and applications for approximate nonnegative matrix factorization.* Computational Statistics
and Data Analysis, 52(1):155–173, 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We calculate
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{trace}
\|X - XWG^T\|_F^2 = \\
\tr[(X - XWG^T)^T(X - XWG^T)] =\\
\tr(X^TX) - 2\tr(X^TXWG^T) + 
\tr(GW^TX^TXWG^T)
$$
Note, however, that **order matters** in that last term.